# Photoshop: use the pen tool without anti-aliasing?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, anti-aliasing

I'm building some "8-bit" style sprites in Photoshop, and using the pen tool so that I can scale them for different resolutions.

The problem is that they are coming out anti-aliased, which I don't want.  Is there a way to turn off anti-aliasing with the Photoshop pen tool?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

1. Once you have created each shape (I assume that's what you're doing -- if not, that's how you should do this so you can see what you're doing) and scaled to taste, select its **path** using the Path Selection Tool (black arrow version).

   [image: Black arrow, path selection tool]
2. Copy.

   <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> <kbd>(Cmnd)⌘+C</kbd>
3. Create a new, empty layer and Paste. You now have a duplicate of the path on a new raster layer and can hide the vector (shape) layer.

   [image: Create new layer]
4. From the Paths panel flyout, select either "Fill Path" or "Stroke Path" and clear the "Anti-alias" checkbox.

   [image: Fill Path] [image: Uncheck Anti-alias]

Comment: There's also **Stroke path with brush** button at the bottom. It uses current brush settings to stroke, so if you're in pencil mode, the line won't be antialiased.