# Anti alias using pen tool in photoshop doesn't help to make edges smooth

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pen-tool, anti-aliasing

Whenever I use Pen Tool, I can't make my edges smooth enough. I, of course, set the feather radius to 0 and checking the check-box next to the Anti-aliased, but obviously this isn't working as I want it to.

Same thing was with the Brushes, until I reduced the percentage of Spacing in the brush settings. Perhaps there's something like that for the Pen tool as well? Anything?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Edges look smooth to me. They actually look a bit blurred which means your vector shape is not set to "Align Edges" to the pixel grid.

Comment: Luciano, thanks, but what do you mean by "vector shape"? I didn't find anything alike. Also, if the prev. image looks ok to you, take a look at the second one - you must see the edges of the "S" aren't as smooth as it would be with the brush, for example

Comment: What is the zoom level set to in Photoshop?  Try setting it to 100% and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thank Billy, but it didn't help. I was using 100% zoom while Pen tooling it

Comment: I can't replicate the problem when creating a vector shape layer in Photoshop. My result looks significantly smoother than yours. See [here](http://imgur.com/Fzfin3t). Did you rasterize the vector at any point, and perhaps rescale it?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than duplicate something already here (In a round about way)
I provided the following link;
[Photoshop: use the pen tool without anti-aliasing?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4299/photoshop-use-the-pen-tool-without-anti-aliasing)

Obviously instead of Turning AntiAliasing off in the example ;), leave it on and change the Feather amount to whatever you desire.

I this doesn't provide the control or preciseness you're after, try using the Blur Tool across the edge. More work and requires some dexterity but results can be very good.

Hope this helps

[anti-aliasing](/questions/tagged/anti-aliasing)[pen-tool](/questions/tagged/pen-tool)

Answer (score 0):

*Everything* must use pixels to display on a monitor. It is not possible to get a "razor smooth" path if there's an angle or curve. Pixels are square and can't be "cut" to match non-perpendicular edges.

The only way to decrease the *visible* edges of pixels is to use a monitor with a higher [pixel density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density). That will make the edges less visible to you, but will not change the nature of the artwork.

It's not possible to remove all indications of pixels on curves or angles. This is just the nature of pixel-based displays.

The posted sample images look perfectly normal to me.

Comment: Yes but the anti aliasing adobe uses leaves something to be desired so it can be done better.