# Illustrator 2017: How do I export a PNG with a diagonal line that is not pixelated?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, png, image-quality

I am trying to create a PNG in Illustrator. It looks smooth and how I want it to look, until I export it as a PNG.

I understand that selecting PNG vs PNG 8 can make a difference but I have not experienced it really doing anything.

I have also tried Interlaced v not Interlaced and that has not improved it either.

Is this something where PNG is the wrong format? I am exporting for digital use, but first as an asset in InDesign and they need to be crisp, not pixelated as they have been.

[image: This is what I want it to look like]

[image: This is what it looks like when exported.]

Comment: Why are you exporting the image as a PNG?  What is your goal here?  What are you trying to create with InDesign?  Why are you zooming in on a raster image?

Comment: I am building a document with assets built in illustrator. Eventually, the assets will be used in digital formats so I think the below point about using a native illustrator file is the way to go here. Also, I zoomed in on that second one to show how it became pixelated. I have a slight obsession about things appearing unpixelated, so I was just attempting to really make this as unpixelated as possible. (I understand that in digital format, these are literally made of pixels so it will never be totally unpixelated). Sounds like that method I was using will not produce what I am looking for.

Comment: Zoom in on pixels, and you will see them!!  PNG images are raster images, all raster images are made of pixels. Follow the advice given by @Metis below - place native .ai files in InDesign instead.  AI files are vector, they have no pixels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See here: [Anti alias using pen tool in photoshop doesn't help to make edges smooth](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/95538/anti-alias-using-pen-tool-in-photoshop-doesnt-help-to-make-edges-smooth/95558#95558)

In short, **everything on screen** is displayed via pixels. Your second image appears to be "zoomed in" or enlarged making pixels more visible.

**If you are using Illustrator... save as a native .ai file and place *that* in InDesign.**

I can think of no direct reason to use the PNG format for Illustrator constructed artwork destined for use in InDesign. InDesign supports the import of .ai files just fine.